# Retrieve data from mongodb using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using official mongodb driver for c# in my test project and i've already insert document from c# web application to mongodb. In mongo console, db.blog.find() can display entries I've inserted. but when i tried to retrieve them, .net throw a exception

**"System.InvalidOperationException: ReadString can only be called when CurrentBsonType is String, not when CurrentBsonType is ObjectId."**

my entity class is very simple

```
namespace MongoDBTest
{
    public class Blog
    {
        public String _id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public String Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my retrieve code

```
public List<Blog> List()
{
    MongoCollection collection = md.GetCollection<Blog>("blog");
    MongoCursor<Blog> cursor = collection.FindAllAs<Blog>();
    cursor.SetLimit(5);
    return cursor.ToList();
}
```

can anybody help me out? thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose you just need mark your blog Id with `BsonId` (and insert id yourself) attribute:

```
public class Blog
{
    [BsonId]
    public String Id {get;set;}

    public String Title{get;set;}
}
```

And all should be okay. Issue was because you not marked what field will be Mongodb _id and driver generated _id field with type ObjectId. And when driver trying deserialize it back he can't convert ObjectId to String.

Complete example:

```
MongoCollection collection = md.GetCollection<Blog>("blog");
var blog = new Blog(){Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString(), 
                      Title = "First Blog"};
collection .Insert(blog);

MongoCursor<Blog> cursor = collection.FindAllAs<Blog>();
cursor.SetLimit(5);

var list = cursor.ToList();
```

Comment: hi Andrew Orsich, I've inserted document using **BsonDocument** and mongodb auto generate ObjectId for document and store it, when i use MongoCollection<Blog> and call FindAllAs<Blog> method, ReadString method throws exception. **So i change MongoCollection<Blog> to MongoCollection<BsonDocument> and traversal cursor object in foreach statement to convert each document to blog object**. Anyway, ur reply help me resolved my problem, thank u :)

Comment: An easier fix would be to change the datatype of your ID to ObjectId and decorate it with [BsonId]. I ran into the same error message, and making that change fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieving the data from the MongoDB using C# is pretty simple and there are three different ways the data can be rolled out for frontend

1. List
2. Cursor
3. linq

   ```
   using (var cursor = await col.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync())
   {
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
       foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(doc);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

the above code Shows to retrieve the data using cursors.
[Referrence](http://goo.gl/fQ6VB9)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my [sample project](https://github.com/amitstefen/mongo_app) at github. Off late, I've become really interested in MongoDB. This application shows many useful things that might interest you as well; repository pattern with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The type and name of the id member should be different as follows

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

Where `ObjectId` is in the namespace `MongoDB.Bson`