# Retrieve info from MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

So I'm really new to non relational databases and I'm trying to retrieve information I have already stored, the [tutorial on their site](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/) only shows how to *get* the data, but not how to handle it and since for some reason it only uses "var" to declare variables I'm lost when it comes to the data type they're using.

Other threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772261/retrieve-data-from-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver) seem to declare their variables explicitly, but for some reason I can't do the same, neither can I use the ToList() method.

The code I'm currently using is just like the one shown in the tutorial, following this (or any other method) how can I get the information I want? I know the method successfully returns *something* but I want to know how can I use it?

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Events");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Event", "Idoru");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Just to give some background, I'm storing scheduled events, so I'm trying to retrieve everything in my "Events" collection that has the event name "Idoru", that (I suppose) would also give me the other 2 fields which are date and description. Although I'm planning on storing other types of data in other collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've just realised that you are using the 2.0 driver since your sample code uses the [Builders](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_1.htm).[Filter](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1.htm).[Eq](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Eq.htm) I've updated the answer accordingly.

When you retrieve a collection it's of the type [IMongoCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1.htm). You can retrieve it by BsonDocument or by a specific type, like GetCollection<Event> if you have an Event class that's serializable to Bson.

All the API in the new MongoDriver are async, so your only choice is to call .Result on the tasks returned to use them synchronously.

When you invoke [Find](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm) on it with your query, you get an [IFindFluent](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IFindFluent_2.htm) back. You can invoke ToListAsync() on it to get your list of objects.

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Events");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Event", "Idoru");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Of course you can do:

```
MongoCollection<Event> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Events");
var filter = Builders<Event>.Filter.Eq(q => q.Name == "Idoru");
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
// result is na IList<Event> now.
```

If you'd rather work with Event directly, and provided you have the appropriately serializable event class.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a new driver. Is there a way (in the old driver, since I'm having some issues with the old one) to call the Find method into a list without it being async? Since I kinda want to return the result and I am already waiting for it to happen, just like the example I showed in my post. The link you shared does use await even with the cursor method.